# replace data with regular expressions in Visual Studio Code

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, coldfusion

I have been trying to replace in Visual Studio Code a string of characters using regular expressions since there are several queries and files, I have the following code of what I want to do:

```
<cfquery datasource='#cdc#' username='#user#' password='#password#' name='RS_List_Lib'>
              
      SELECT fun_ctl_save_type(#id_inm#,'#arc_doc#'); 

 </cfquery>

<cfquery datasource='#cdc#' username='#user#' password='#password#' name='RS_List_Lib'>

      SELECT * FROM fun_ctl_proyect_int_show(#id_inm#);

</cfquery>
```

What I want to do is replace what it uses "#parameter#" with:

```
<cfqueryparam value = "#parameter#" CFSQLType = "CF_SQL_INTEGER">
```

However, I want not to modify what is inside the "" label and only modify what is in the query so that it gives me this result:

```
<cfquery datasource='#cdc#' username='#user#' password='#password#' name='RS_List_Lib'>
              
      SELECT fun_ctl_save_type(<cfqueryparam value = "#id_inm#" CFSQLType = "CF_SQL_INTEGER">, <cfqueryparam value = "#arc_doc#" CFSQLType = "CF_SQL_INTEGER">); 

</cfquery>


<cfquery datasource='#cdc#' username='#user#' password='#password#' name='RS_List_Lib'>

      SELECT * FROM fun_ctl_proyect_int_show(<cfqueryparam value = "#id_inm#" CFSQLType = "CF_SQL_INTEGER">);

</cfquery>
```

I try this regular expression with this but it doesn't work for me:

```
(<cfquery\s+(?:(?!>).)*?>!?)*(SELECT\s(.*)+((\s*#\w+#\s*(?:,\s*#\w+#\s*)*).)?)
```

since all the "SELECT..."And with this other one it takes all the values that are inside "#parameter#" and puts them together and not being stopped:

```
(<cfquerys+(?:(?!>).) *?>!?) *(?<=[(])(.*?) (?=))
```

Finally I still have this regular expression `:(s*#w+#s*(?:,s*#w+#s*)*)` to identify me all those who use "#parameter#" but replace those who are inside the "" tag that do not have to `<cfquery>` be modified if not kept the same and only modify those who have the queries.

I hope you can help me.

I already tried these expressions, but I do not know what else I can modify, since I am not very good with them.

REGEX 1:

```
(\s*#\w+#\s*(?:,\s*#\w+#\s*)*)
```

REGEX 2:

```
(<cfquery\s+(?:(?!>).)*?>!?)*(?<=[\(])(.*?)(?=\))
```

Comment: Do `#id_inm#` and `'#arc_doc#'` appear ONLY in those SELECT lines?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `#id_inm#` and `'#arc_doc#` occur only in a `Select` line as your examples show try this, see [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/c5pXmt/1).

Find: `(#id_inm#)|'(#arc_doc#)'`
Replace: `<cfqueryparam value = "$1$2" CFSQLType = "CF_SQL_INTEGER">`